# 'During today' or 'During the day'?

Tags: grammaticality

> The instructions will be up during today.
>
> The instructions will be up during the day.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Barrie's answer, they both seem correct to me, but they do mean different things.

If the instructions are up ***"during the day"***, then I might not expect them to be up at other times, such as overnight.  It depends what "the day" means to your audience, but I wouldn't expect something that is up "during the day" to be available at, say, 9pm.

If the instructions are due to be be up ***"during today"***, I would expect them to start being available at some point today, and to remain available once they arrived.

Comment: Yes, the point is, that, the preposition ‘during’ can stand before the noun ‘today’.

Answer (score 2):

**"During the day"** is definitely correct usage. "During today" sounds off to me, and Google seems to agree. All the hits for "during today" seem to either reference the Today Show or be part of a longer phrase, as in "during today's press conference..."

For this particular case, though, I would probably just say, **"The instructions will be up today."** (Adding the word "during" makes it sound as if once night falls, the instructions will be removed.)

Comment: ‘Some small, though slightly longer period energy out of the east north-east will begin to filter in during today and into tomorrow.’ (Australian ‘Daily Telegraph’, 6 December 1975)

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, but they mean different things.